# Terragrunt with local modules

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I'm trying to use terragrunt to access a local module using the live/remote double-repo techinique discussed in the Terragrunt [documentation](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-terraform-code-dry/).

When I run `terragrunt plan` locally, all is well, and I get no errors.

But when I run it from a second repo, I get these errors:

```
Upgrading modules...
- common in 
╷
│ Error: Unreadable module directory
│ 
│ Unable to evaluate directory symlink: lstat ../common: no such file or
│ directory
╵
╷
│ Error: Failed to read module directory
│ 
│ Module directory  does not exist or cannot be read.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unreadable module directory
│ 
│ Unable to evaluate directory symlink: lstat ../common: no such file or
│ directory
╵
╷
│ Error: Failed to read module directory
│ 
│ Module directory  does not exist or cannot be read.
╵
```

Here the path hierarchy in the "Remote" repo:

```
├project
├──terragrunt.hcl
├──common
   ├──main.tf
├──my-stack
   ├── main.tf
   ├──terragrunt.hcl
```

The code for `project/my-stack/main.tf` is:

```
module "common" {  
  source = "../common/"
}
...
```

For `project/my-stack/terragrunt.hcl`:

```
include "root" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}
```

And for `project/terragrunt.hcl`:

```
remote_state{...}
```

In the above scenarios, all is good and terragrunt runs without error.  The errors occur only when running from the "live` repo.

Here the path hierarchy in the "Live" repo:

```
├live
├──terragrunt.hcl
├──my-live-stack
   ├──terragrunt.hcl
```

For `live/my-live-stack/terragrunt.hcl`:

```
terraform {
  source = "git::git@bitbucket.com:my-company/my-repo.git//my-project?ref=dev"
}
include "root" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}
```

And for `project/terragrunt.hcl`:

```
remote_state{...}
```

I've tried adding `terraform{}` commands and other recommended command blocks, but none seem to work.  There must be something simple that I am doing wrong here.

EDIT: It turns out the git commits had not been applied in the `../common` directory, hence no files existed and so the error message was correct.